# putting elements from vector into queue then clearing vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl, queue

I'm looking for the simplest way(algorithm?) to push an entire vector onto a queue and then delete the vector. I think there are a few ways to do this but I'm not sure which is best, or if all of them are correct. Option 1 is to use `vector.pop_back()`, but I'd have to go backwards through the `for` loop in this case, which isn't a problem since the order the objects go into the queue from the vector do not matter

```
for(unsigned i = vector.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    queue.push(vector[i]);
    vector.pop_back();
}
```

Option 2 is to use vector.erase(). Also is it okay to do i < vector.size()? Because when I looked online for iterating through vectors I found a lot of i != vector.size() instead

```
for(unsigned i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++){
    queue.push(vector[i]);
    vector.erase[i];
}
```

My issue here is that if I erase vector[i], does vector [i+1] now become vector[i]? Or does vector[i] become a Null value?

My 3rd option would be to just erase it all at the end

```
for(unsigned i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++){
    queue.push(vector[i]);
}
vector.erase(vector.begin(), vector.end());
```

Just for clarity, I don't want to get rid of the vector variable itself, just empty it after putting it into the queue, because it will eventually store a bunch of new things to dump into a queue again and again.

Comment: An unsigned value will always be `>= 0`, so this won't work. Also, if the vector is empty to begin with, you will have undefined behaviour. `while (!v.empty()) { foo(v.back()); v.pop_back();}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind the objects being present in both the queue and the vector for a while, just do the simplest thing: your 3rd option, just with a `clear()` instead to be explicit what you're doing:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++){
    queue.push(vector[i]);
}
vector.clear();
```

Of course, in C++11, you could use a range-based `for` loop, and even move the items out of the vector to avoid needless copies:

```
for (auto &elem : vector) {
  queue.push(std::move(elem));
}
vector.clear();
```

Comment: What would happen to `elem` ? Would it vaporize? Wont exist in `vector`? I am bit confused!

Comment: @Ajay: It is still in the vector, but had its data moved away (useless for an `int`). It is in an unspecified _but valid_ state (yes, vague). Then is immediately destroyed by the `std::vector<T>::clear` operation.

Answer (score 0):

**A)**

```
for(unsigned i = vector.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    queue.push(vector[i]);
    vector.pop_back();
}
```

This should be a bit less efficient then **C)**

**B)**

```
for(unsigned i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++){
    queue.push(vector[i]);
    vector.erase[i];
}
```

*"My issue here is that if I erase vector[i], does vector [i+1] now become vector[i]? Or does vector[i] become a Null value?"*

Erase[i] doesn't work at all. You could ruse erase(vector.begin()) pulling elements from the vectors head one by one,  but its not very efficient and the whole loop should end up with O(N^2/2) since your deleting from the vectors head.

**C)**

```
for(unsigned i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++){
        queue.push(vector[i]);
    }
    vector.clear();
```

Should be the most efficient way to go.

**Note**

The result of **A** and **B** since in **A** you're pulling elements from the tail while taking them from the head in **C**

Answer (score 0):

Unless the element-type is large, you can't do much (except `move` which @Angew suggested). If element size is small, there is no benefit of `move` either - the memory layout of both `vector` and `queue` are different. If element-type is large, you may consider using pointers (in a `list` or `vector`) of elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use a deque instead of queue then you could do an insert and insert all the elements at once.

Something like

```
template <class T, template <typename, typename> class Container>
class BlockQueue : public Container<T, std::allocator<T>>
{
public:
    BlockQueue() : Container<T, std::allocator<T>>()
    {
    }
    void push( T val )
    {
        this->push_back( val );
    }
    void push( const std::vector<T>& newData )
    {
        this->insert( this->end(), newData.begin(), newData.end() );
    }
};
```